# CMD - How to check if you are connected to the internet?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to check if my computer is connected to a network and prints out a bool statement if I'm connected or not. Nothing more...

Comment: @CAMOBAP Hmm, I just need a simple batch script that will check the PC's connectivity to a network and prints out if it's connected or not. Nothing more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply ping an IP address from the target network and check the result:

```
ping -n 2 192.168.2.1 > nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" goto connected
echo Not Connected
goto end

:connected
echo Connected

:end
```

Of course you will have to provide a valid IP address that will reply to pings.

Comment: Thanks! Really worked!

Comment: Follow up question, what if I'm connected but has no internet access? I tried it but it also says connected even tho there's no internet access...

Comment: @pajanustan Simply replace the IP address with one that's on the internet. You could also use a DNS name like `stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Another similar way :

```
@echo off&cls
ping -n 2 www.google.com >nul && echo connected || echo not connected
```

Comment: Okay, I tried [ping -n 2 google.com>nul && echo connected & pause>nul || echo not connected & pause>nul]. Yeah it says connected when I'm connected to a network, but when not, it outputs nothing...

Comment: Then I tried [... | echo not connected & pause>nul]. The output was correct when I'm disconnected, but when I'm connected, It outputs both "connected" and "not connected" at the same time...